# How to remove the default order - set by Django admin - changelist on primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Django admin automatically sets sorting on primary key - when rendered on changelist (Django Admin) - which causes quite a lot of query cost on data of 500-600k records. The same issue is faced due to which the page is giving 504.

How can the default sorting be removed?

I have checked and the ordering is set in base class (`main.py`) in the `get_queryset` method. Overriding that particular method causing extra queries.
What is the best way to remove that default ordering?

Comment: Can you give me some example with models.

Comment: This is done for pagination purposes, since otherwise the next page can reder the same items.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What if i don't require the pagination to show me the current result. Actually this is causing my query very slow. How can i remove it without having extra queries added.

Comment: @Devendra: it is not about the current result, it should render pagination completely useless, since regardless on what page you are, each time it then shows *random* elements. It would thus mean that the first and the fifth page could (strictly) speaking, be identical for example. It would thus be impossible to look at the objects.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem for your guidance. I can see you have quite a expertise in django. Being a learner, i have been stuck in one more issue, hope you help me clearing that too. Actually, i have overide "has_add_permission" in one of my modeladmin and it has been called automatically in my other modelAdmin classes too. I researched and found that it is happening due to "each_context" method called every time. Is there any way we can stop that thing calling on each model admin. I can present you the scenario if required. Thanx in advance.